# SQL Server How to Select * from table_name where in (@parameter )

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have data @P = (000000000111,000000000222) from table_B

---

this code can exec complete

```
select * from table_A where id in (000000000111,000000000222)
```

but this code can not exec complete

```
declare @P nvarchar(100)
set @P = (select id from table_B)
select @P
select * from merchant where id in (@P)
```

how to this code can exec complete

Comment: using `select * from merchant where id in (select id from table_B)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need a parameter:

```
select *
from merchant
where id in (select id from table_b);
```

I would suggest `exists` instead, but that is a nuance.

If you did want to store the values, you would use a table:

```
declare @p table (id nvarchar(100));

insert into @p (id)
    select id
    from table_b;

select *
from merchant m
where exists (select 1 from @p p where p.id = m.id);
```

Of course, this is just a more verbose version of the first query.

Answer (score 1):

`in` is a set operation, it works with sets, not with strings are you are assuming.

There are multiple ways to select rows from one table where the id exists in another, for example

```
select * from merchant m
where exists (select * from table_B b where b.id=m.id)
```

or in line with your thinking

```
select * from merchant
where id in (select id from table_B)
```

Here, the `in` operates on a *set* not a string.